# Angular : set method parameter in subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to use subscribe in a method and pass my variable(cities) as a parameter to method.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  cities:any;
  constructor(private myApiService: MyApiService) {
  myMethod(this.cities);
  }
  myMethod(value:any)
  {
    this.myApiService.run("myparameter").subscribe((p: any) => {
      value = p.Cities;
      console.log(this.cities);// result-> []
      console.log(p.cities);   // result-> (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  });
}
```

My variable didn't change. I know that I can't return data from method because of it is an async call.I tried using "ref" (like C#) but It didn't work. I don't want to use "map".

Comment: Invoke the method inside `susbscribe` callback `.subscribe(res=>this.yourMethod(res.Cities)..`

Comment: @Vikas I didn't understand

Comment: Based on my understanding you want to call a method with parameter after your subscription is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because `cities` param is passed to method as value. You can achieve what you want by using little trick:

If response from service is array:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  cities = [];
  constructor(private myApiService: MyApiService) {
  myMethod(this.cities);
  }
  myMethod(value:any)
  {
    this.myApiService.run("myparameter").subscribe((p: any) => {
      p.Cities.forEach(city => value.push(city));
  });
}
```

If response is object:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  cities = {val: {}};
  constructor(private myApiService: MyApiService) {
  myMethod(this.cities);
  }
  myMethod(value:any)
  {
    this.myApiService.run("myparameter").subscribe((p: any) => {
      value.val = p.Cities;
  });
}
```